# Assimp mesh missing bones

Tags: animation, assimp

I'm working on skeletal animation and got stuck on this really weird issue.

Using ASSIMP to import a .dae model.

I have loaded the model's bone hierarchy (nodes), but the **mesh->mBones**
contains only 10 bones, while there are 29 total. I thought there are only those which are active during the transforms, but nope, that is not the case. Active bones are missing.

When reading the scene, I'm using **aiProcess_ValidateDataStructure**
Importer throws no errors.

The exact problem is I don't have all the aiBone structures needed to obtain bone weights. Is it bad exporting or something else?

I'm attaching the object model and the scene. Thanks for all help.
https://skfb.ly/CDIu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem turned out to be the biped system.

Raw bones work just fine!

Comment: So how do you read the "Raw Bones" out of assimp ?